# How to enable Wifi connection in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 along with Windows 8.1. My Wifi is working in windows but not in Ubuntu. I gave the following command in the command terminal.

```
 nmcli nm
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN      
running         connected       enabled         enabled    enabled         enabled   
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0806]
```

Though it says wifi is enabled, yet it's not working. I have an Acer Aspire E5-573 laptop.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: This adapter is not supported in linux yet.

Comment: Is a there a way out?

Comment: Well. There is a driver ath10k. And firmware can be found. But there is no ready solution for this chip. And patch to kernel is needed. Nothing easy.

Comment: I suggest reporting it to launchpad. The solution can be made, but not here for sure.

Comment: @DavidFoerster This is WRONG.

Answer (score 1):

This wireless adapter is not supported by linux kernel.

I suggest reporting this to launchpad. In this case there is a chance to get a fix. But you will need to co-operate with testing.

Connect your laptop to internet by wire and run in terminal

```
ubuntu-bug linux
```

and follow the instructions.

You can also post a link to your question here for reference.

Comment: Will it work on ubuntu 15.04 ?

Comment: Bug reporting works on all Ubuntu releases.

Comment: Sorry I mean the does  wifi works on ubuntu 15.04 ? for specified adapter.

Comment: No. There is the same kernel in 15.04.