# wireless not there on a aspire e 15

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

Bought an acer aspire e15. came with widows 7 or 8. Disabled the new boot and could see Ubuntu USB, installed but no wireless. LAN(wired) worked fine.

Realized had put 32 bit, now 'trying' 14.4 64 bit from  USB made using the start up disk creator from 32bit.

Still can't see Wireless (section is not there when i open the network area on top)

See http://postimg.org/image/gll0p0bxt/920b14c9/
**Command :**

```
rfkill list 
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no 

1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**Output of network script**

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 24 Jul 2015 13:15 UTC +0000

Booted last: 24 Jul 2015 13:01 UTC +0000

Script from: 14 Jul 2015 17:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Release: 14.04 Codename: trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

noprompt, cdrom-detect/try-usb=true, persistent, file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed, boot=casper, initrd=/casper/initrd.lz, quiet, splash, --, maybe-ubiquity

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)  Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0987]   Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)     Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0806]

04:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1299] (rev a1)

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1bcf:2c81 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04ca:3015 Lite-On Technology Corp.
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0930:6545 Toshiba Corp. Kingston DataTraveler 102 Flash Drive / HEMA Flash Drive 2 GB / PNY Attache 4GB Stick
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth  Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no 1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN     Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwlwifi               179412  0
cfg80211              494330  1
iwlwifi acer_wmi       32522  0
sparse_keymap          13948  1
acer_wmi mxm_wmi       13021  1
nouveau video          20128  3
i915,acer_wmi,nouveau wmi     19193  3
acer_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.4  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:51939 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:32765 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:69204275 (69.2 MB)  TX bytes:2643770 (2.6 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table Destination     Gateway         Genmask        Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      3641     1  0 13:01 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------   Type:              Wired   Driver:            r8169   State:             connected   Default:     yes   HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.4
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main] NetworkingEnabled=true WirelessEnabled=true WWANEnabled=true WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main] plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown] managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Etc/UTC (based on set time zone)

country 00:     (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)     (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS  (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS     (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS  (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[iwlwifi] filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko license:        GPL author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com> version:        in-tree: description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux firmware:      iwlwifi-100-5.ucode firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode firmware:     iwlwifi-135-6.ucode firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode firmware:      iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode firmware:    iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode firmware:    iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode firmware:    iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode firmware:    iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode srcversion:     D335B9FC08B25C4ADA0BD33 depends:  cfg80211 intree:         Y vermagic:       3.16.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions  signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key sig_key:        7B:E2:A7:20:0F:17:F0:0C:A0:11:F7:0E:5A:87:4C:37:E3:E0:F6:BE sig_hashalgo:   sha512 parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int) parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint) parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int) parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool) parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (defualt: 0 dB) (int) parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable (default: 1) (int) parm:    nvm_file:NVM file name (charp) parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: N) (bool) parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool) parm:  led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int) parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool) parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int) parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211] filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko description:    wireless configuration support license:        GPL author:         Johannes Berg srcversion:     DEE8EAA48495E392CD51C2D depends:         intree:         Y vermagic:       3.16.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload modversions  signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key sig_key:        7B:E2:A7:20:0F:17:F0:0C:A0:11:F7:0E:5A:87:4C:37:E3:E0:F6:BE sig_hashalgo:   sha512 parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp) parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlwifi] 11n_disable: 0 amsdu_size_8K: 0 antenna_coupling: 0 bt_coex_active: Y fw_monitor: N fw_restart: Y led_mode: 0 nvm_file: (null) power_level: 0 power_save: N swcrypto: 0 uapsd_disable: N wd_disable: 1

[cfg80211] cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf] blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf] blacklist evbug blacklist usbmouse blacklist usbkbd blacklist eepro100 blacklist de4x5 blacklist eth1394 blacklist snd_intel8x0m blacklist snd_aw2 blacklist i2c_i801 blacklist prism54 blacklist bcm43xx blacklist garmin_gps blacklist asus_acpi blacklist snd_pcsp blacklist pcspkr blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf] alias net-pf-3 off alias net-pf-6 off alias net-pf-9 off alias net-pf-11 off alias net-pf-12 off alias net-pf-19 off alias net-pf-21 off alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf] remove iwlwifi \ (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o
-e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \ && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf] softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf] options cirrus modeset=1 options mgag200 modeset=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169) SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

On windows wireless is working (can boot back in to it if I choose the new boot way : press f2 on start up...)

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/651341/how-to-enable-wifi-connection-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: What are you saying? its a bug with no fix? Report and live without wireless ?

Comment: It is a bug with no fix *yet*. I suggest an inexpensive USB wireless in the meantime.

Comment: thanks will get a USB wireless. Wish I had looked at the list of supported hardware first. I see few brands but not acer there :(

Comment: Acer is generally well supported but this is a fairly new wireless device included in new Acers. The laptop otherwise and the company are just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't even try installing various wireless drivers. This E 15 series has very new technologies. and the wireless drivers for this serious are only available for windows 10(does not have drivers for other windows versions).... Sadly wireless will not work in ubuntu 14 or 15 as well.
My solution is to use a wireless usb adapter like this [http://www.amazon.com/TP-LINK-TL-WN821N-Wireless-Adapter-300Mbps/dp/B002T4D3M2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002T4D3M2)

Comment: mine has windows 8.1 works ... ubuntu dual boot with USB wireless is okay too. only need to switch the boot sector to change allow linux