# Acer Aspire E14 ubuntu wifi problem

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, acer

I am very new in Ubuntu platform. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in my acer Aspire E 14 laptop. I did not find proper solution to connect it with WiFi. If I go to "Additional Drivers" tab under  "System Settings > Software & Update" I can't see any drive for WiFi. There is a option of my laptop for toggling WiFi by pressing (Fn + F3), tested by pressing this but did not work.

Please give me proper solution how can I connect my acer laptop with WiFi.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Welcome to askubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Please could you supply us with errors that your are receiving when trying to connect? Also I am sure that the following tutorial should point you in the right direction [Fix wifi issues in ubuntu](http://itsfoss.com/fix-no-wireless-network-ubuntu/)

Comment: @Moderators I know this is not an answer but I can't comment till I have 50 rep

Comment: RiaanV thanks for ans. Actually I did not get any wifi signal to connect. I did not get any driver list in the "Additional Drivers" tab like http://prntscr.com/8tm287.

Comment: Please click on the the link in my answer to resolve the problem

Comment: Not working as your link

Comment: It could be same problem as listed http://askubuntu.com/q/652199/462668